# How to store mysql column info in an array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

The site I am creating will allow users to update their status. The only reasonable way I could think of storing the information would be to post a new line to my database for every post they make. I can associate the posts with their usernames on the same line. The problem is that no matter what I try nothing works on retrieving the info. I need to select the column where their status will be held and store all the status's in an array. Is this even possible? I am using PHP. As all the code I have used has been very ineffective I will not include it. Any help would be VERY appreciated!

Comment: Even if your code is ineffective, you should post it so we have something to go on.

Comment: What is your database schema? What table names and column names?

Comment: Please be more specific, what have you tried? Can you put some more details?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
<?php
$q = $db->prepare("DESCRIBE tablename");
$q->execute();
$result = $q->fetchAll();
var_dump($result);
```